# Sheet of BottomSheetScaffold automatically expands on recomposition

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android, bottom-sheet

In Jetpack Compose, I have a `BottomSheetScaffold` with some content. This content is observed from the ViewModel, like this:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetContent = { SheetContent(sheetData = viewModel.sheetData) }
) {}
```

So whenever `viewModel.sheetData` changes, a recomposition is triggered. Whenever this happens, the bottom sheet automatically expands. Is this a bug or a feature? Can I disable this? I am using the newest version: 1.1.0-alpha01

Edit: Here is an example using `LaunchedEffect` instead of a ViewModel.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    var addSheetData by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        delay(2000)
        addSheetData = true
    }

    BottomSheetScaffold(sheetContent = {
        if (addSheetData) {
            Column {
                Text(text = "Text1", fontSize = 36.sp)
                Text(text = "Text2", fontSize = 36.sp)
                Text(text = "Text3", fontSize = 36.sp)
                Text(text = "Text4", fontSize = 36.sp)
                Text(text = "Text5", fontSize = 36.sp)
            }
        }
    }, sheetBackgroundColor = Color.LightGray) {}
}
```

The sheet with the 5 texts expands automatically.

Comment: If you wanna your question to be answered, you wanna make time for an expert to get working sample with reproducible problem as fast as possible. Perfectly I should just paste your code into my sample project and see the problem as fast as I run it. Please update your code to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It should include sample data like strings/numbers, and you can update it over time with `LaunchedEffect`

Comment: @Philip Added an example, as requested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems a bug.
Currently (`1.0.x` and `1.1.0-alpha01`) it happens when the `sheetContentHeight` < `sheetPeekHeight`.
In this case the `scaffoldState.bottomSheetState` result `expanded` also if the content sheet is not displayed.

You can easily verify it using in your code:

```
sheetBackgroundColor = if (scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isCollapsed) Color.LightGray else Color.Yellow
```

When `addSheetData == false` the background color becomes `Yellow`. When you recompose the composable, since the state is expanded, the content sheet is full expanded.

As workaround you can use something like:

```
  sheetContent = { 
        if (!addSheetData){
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(60.dp))
        }    

        if (addSheetData) {
            Column {
                Text(text = "Text1", fontSize = 36.sp)
                Text(text = "Text2", fontSize = 36.sp)
                Text(text = "Text3", fontSize = 36.sp)
                Text(text = "Text4", fontSize = 36.sp)
                Text(text = "Text5", fontSize = 36.sp)
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Interesting! Apparently it always starts as expanded, really weird. I'll use this workaround for now, thanks so much!

Comment: Is there an open issue for this? I don't see it mentioned in 1.2.X release notes

Edit: It looks like there is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202868798

Assigned 8 months ago...

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug with `BottomSheetScaffold`. However you can try an alternative to this which is `ModalBottomSheetLayout`. More info about this composable can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#ModalBottomSheetLayout(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material.ModalBottomSheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0)).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an initial value:

```
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(
            initialValue = BottomSheetValue.Collapsed,
        )
    )
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around the issue by creating a custom state that manages the scaffold state, and shows the sheet content depending on my custom state because the scaffold state always returns to `Expanded`.

Here is my solution:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun CustomBottomSheet(
    customBottomSheetState: CustomBottomSheetState = rememberCustomBottomSheetState(remember { CustomBottomSheetState() }),
    topBar: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
    sheetContent: @Composable() (ColumnScope.() -> Unit),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val scaffoldState: BottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
    customBottomSheetState.scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    // this to handle updating the state when collapsing by swiping the sheet down
    if (scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isCollapsed) {
        customBottomSheetState.currentValue.value = CustomBottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    }
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
        topBar = topBar,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetShape = BottomSheetShape,
        sheetContent = {
            if (customBottomSheetState.isExpanded()) {
                sheetContent()
            }
        }
    ) {
        Box(Modifier.padding(it)) {
            content()
        }
    }
}

@Stable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
class CustomBottomSheetState constructor(
    initialValue: MutableState<CustomBottomSheetValue> = mutableStateOf(CustomBottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
) {
    var currentValue = initialValue
    var scaffoldState: BottomSheetScaffoldState? = null
    suspend fun expand() {
        scaffoldState?.bottomSheetState?.expand()
        currentValue.value = CustomBottomSheetValue.Expanded
    }

    suspend fun collapse() {
        scaffoldState?.bottomSheetState?.collapse()
        currentValue.value = CustomBottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    }
    fun isCollapsed(): Boolean {
        return this.currentValue.value == CustomBottomSheetValue.Collapsed
    }

    fun isExpanded(): Boolean {
        return this.currentValue.value == CustomBottomSheetValue.Expanded
    }
}

enum class CustomBottomSheetValue {
    Expanded, Collapsed;
}

@Composable
fun rememberCustomBottomSheetState(bottomSheetState: CustomBottomSheetState = CustomBottomSheetState()) =
    remember(bottomSheetState) { bottomSheetState }
```

And that's how it is used:

```kotlin
    val bottomSheetState = rememberCustomBottomSheetState()
    CustomBottomSheet(topBar = {
        // topbar
    }, customBottomSheetState = bottomSheetState, sheetContent = {
            // sheet
        }) {
        // screen
    }
```

You can modify the parameters to include all of the `BottomSheetScaffold` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix the unwanted recomposition. What happens is whenever it recomposes, it goes back to the `initialValue: SheetValue.`
In my case i'm using `rememberStandardBottomSheetState` which has a default value of `initialValue: SheetValue = PartiallyExpanded` so everytime it recomposes my bottomSheet "minimises" ...

My work around is to set my initial value to a saveable state and updated it whenever my state changes so when it recomposes the bottomSheet keeps its state.

```
var sheetState by remember { mutableStateOf(SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded) }
```

If your bottomSheet can only change via "dragging" you can intercept the states changes via `confirmValueChange` found in `rememberStandardBottomSheetState` in my case i could also expand() / "minimise"() via the dragHandle onClicks. You can take inspiration from my code :

```
    @Composable
    private fun StickyBottomSheet(
        content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
        title: String? = null,
        onStateChange: (BottomSheetState) -> Unit = {}
    ){
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var sheetState by remember { mutableStateOf(SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded) }
    val state = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = sheetState,
        confirmValueChange = { sheetValue ->
            sheetState = sheetValue
            when (sheetValue) {
                SheetValue.Hidden -> false

                SheetValue.Expanded -> {
                    onStateChange(BottomSheetState.Expanded)
                    true
                }

                SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded -> {
                    onStateChange(BottomSheetState.Minimised)
                    true
                }
            }
        }
    )
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(bottomSheetState = state)
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetContent = content,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetShadowElevation = 8.dp,
        sheetDragHandle = {
            DragHandle(
                title = title,
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        if (scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded) {
                            sheetState = SheetValue.Expanded
                            scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
                            onStateChange(BottomSheetState.Expanded)
                        } else {
                            scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.show()
                            onStateChange(BottomSheetState.Dismissed)
                        }
                    }
                },
                expanded = scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.Expanded
            )
        }
    ) {

    }
}

@Composable
private fun DragHandle(title: String?, onClick: () -> Unit = {}, expanded: Boolean){
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.height(56.dp)
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = expanded, enter = fadeIn(), exit = fadeOut()) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .padding(top = 16.dp)
                    .size(width = 32.dp, height = 4.dp)
                    .background(wjColorScheme.outline)
                    .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
            )
            IconButton(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd),
                onClick = { onClick() },
                content = { Icon(R.drawable.ic_close_24 )})
        }
    }
    AnimatedVisibility(!expanded, enter = fadeIn(), exit = fadeOut()) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable { onClick() }
        ) {
            ListItem(
                leadingContent = { Icon(R.drawable.ic_add_24) },
                text2 = title
            )
        }
    }
}
```

}